# how do I open a windows hard drive which is seen as a windows network by ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive, windows

Several times I have attempted to open a Windows hard drive using Ubuntu 64, the latest available to date for AMD 64 chips (it is 18: something). Ubuntu sees the hard drive as a "Windows Network". How do I access this hard drive from the file manager, inside this Ubuntu OS, so I can get to my files?

Comment: Are you sure that the "Windows Network" correspond to your Windows hard drive ? Ubuntu should open NTFS (Windows) hard drive without problem. Is there any error dialog ?

Comment: Sometimes a windows hard drive might be only named XXGB volume or something like acer(your computer maker), this should be above where you see 'other locations'.  It could also be that the windows hard drive is not mounted.  If so open 'disks' app and see if it is mounted.  There are small icons on bottom left.